# DIV overflow should start from left

Tags: css, html

Please see [this diagram](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7Sym6rBXFI5YTQ0dW54dzE2WFU&export=download). Is there any possible ways to bring the red squares to the left side (white squares should stay there) so that the 2nd and 3rd (ONLY) line will start from leftmost position.

Comment: for those whom want to see the image without downloading, simply remove the `&export=download` in the link.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like the next

```
<div id="similarImages">
    <img class="imgBox white" />
    <img class="imgBox white" />
    <img class="imgBox white" />
    <img class="imgBox red" />
    <img class="imgBox red" />
    <img class="imgBox red" />
    <img class="imgBox red" />
</div>
```

in css

```
div#similarImages {
    /* specify width */
}
img.imgBox {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
    float: left;
}
```

feel free to remove `white` and `red`  class names if it's not a need. It's just to tell which image is those white and red ones.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXA87/)